# java: Deleting Element from Array after .split()

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose you have a `String[]` that has been created after a `.split()` which then causes you to have a bunch of empty strings in there i.e.

```
myArray['','hello','thetimes','economist','','','hi']
```

Is there a way to remove them from the `String[]` without having to loop round, detecting if string is empty then adding to new array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove them from the
>   String[] without having to loop round,
>   detecting if string is empty then
>   adding to new array?

No. Arrays have a fixed length.

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier way here.

`String.split("\\s+")` will eliminate those empty strings.

Comment: You can't invoke `.split()` on a `String[]`. I've already split my array on a certain string, for example `String[] hello = someString.split('abc');`, I can't then do a `.split()` on `hello[]`. Or.. perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: @theEconomist:  No, you invoke `.split()` on the `String` itself.  The regex parameter indicates the pattern to split around.  That particular pattern I named matches "one or more whitespace characters", this eliminating the empty `String`s in the resulting array.

Comment: @theEconomist:  Also, if you are splitting around more than whitespace, you can expand your regex to include surrounding whitespace.  For example, `someString.split('abc')` would become `someString.split(\\s*abc\\s*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right MAGIC way:

```
String str = "1, 2,3   4,,  , ,5,,6,  ,";
String arr[] = str.split("(\\s*,\\s*)+");
```

Comment: An example of the output would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions solve only a part of the problem - remove only the trailing empty strings. 
I used:

```
String st = "a,b,c,,d,,f,,,";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(st.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
while (list.remove(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to convert it to a `List`, iterate over that and remove the empty elements, e.g.

```
List<String> parts = new LinkedList<String>(string.split(pattern));
for (Iterator<String> it = parts.iterator();
     it.hasNext();
     ) {
    if (it.next().isEmpty()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
return parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
```

Comment: There will be no empty string after the split!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\s*" + splitString + "\\s*");
```

Where `splitString` is the string on which you were originally splitting.

This extends the split string adding *any* number of whitespaces to it, so that they are realized as part of the splitter, not part of the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is in your regex string which is doing the split. Have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a list of special notations to add like others have been suggesting, such as `\\s`.

If you want to go the easier route than learning regex, you could just iterate through the array and add each non-empty String to an `ArrayList<String>` and then change it back to a fixed size array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple method to remove elements from an array. You can do `replaceAll()` and then call `split` or call `split("\\s+")` with multiple space.